# python seleniumを使っていると処理が止まる？

Tags: python, selenium

初めまして．
pythonでスクレイピングをしています．
しかし，大量に(数十~数百件)下記のようなプログラムでhtmlを得ていると，
`browser.page_source`で処理が止まってしまいます．
エラーが出るわけでもなく，数十分しても動き出しません．

同じような状況の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか．
また，解決した方がいらっしゃいましたら，その方法を教えてください．

よろしくお願いいたします．

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# ブラウザーを起動
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
# Chromeのドライバを得る
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.set_script_timeout = 30
browser.timeout = 30
browser.implicitly_wait = 30
browser.set_page_load_timeout = 30
browser.get(url)
# htmlを取得
html = browser.page_source
```

**追記1**:
コメントありがとうございます．
大量に取得する部分ですが，
urlのリスト`urls = ["https://~~", "https://~~", ...]`といったものを作成し，

```
for url in urls:
  scraping(url)
```

という風に記載しています．
scraping(url)は上記のようなプログラムです．

**追記2**:
コメントありがとうございます．

> scraping(url)は上記のようなプログラムです．

この書き方がよくありませんでした．
すみません．
最初に提示したプログラムがscraping(url)です．
ですので，

```
def scraping(url):
  # ブラウザーを起動
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  # Chromeのドライバを得る
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

  browser.set_script_timeout = 30
  browser.timeout = 30
  browser.implicitly_wait = 30
  browser.set_page_load_timeout = 30
  browser.get(url)
  # htmlを取得
  html = browser.page_source
  return (html)
```

このようなプログラムです．

運がいいときは，止まらずに数百件の処理を行いますが，
悪いと，数件処理した後にhtml = の部分で止まります．

Comment: 提示されたコードは単一のURLから取得する部分だけだと思うので、念のため「大量に取得する」処理を行うコードについても提示してもらった方がアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できます。

Comment: 追記部分についてですが、そのコードは`scraping`の中身を表していません。どこかに`def scraping(...):`というような部分があるはずですので、その中身を記載してください。